# Force stop loop function in IntentService

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, intentservice

There a function in my intent service that works like a countdown. It is called `counter`.

What should be added to IntentService or directly into `counter` to stop this loop after some action in MainActivity?

```
class IntentServiceExample : IntentService("Loop_test") {
    private val CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundService Kotlin"

    companion object {
        val PARAM_OUT_MSG = "None"
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager!!.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        createNotificationChannel()

        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0
        )
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service Kotlin Example")
            .setContentText("kylsha")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onHandleIntent(p0: Intent?) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        val broadcastIntent = Intent()
        broadcastIntent.action = "com.example.intenttest.action.RESPONSE"
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)
        counter(broadcastIntent)
    }

    fun counter(bc: Intent){
        for (i in 1..100){
            bc.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG, i.toString())
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            d("number", i.toString())
            sendBroadcast(bc)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        stopSelf()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a variable in the class.
Create a setter to set the variable true.
In you rcounter routine, check for the variable being set.

```
private val cancelCounter = false
public fun setToCancel() {
    cancelCounter = true
}

/*Stuff*/

fun counter(bc: Intent){
    for (i in 1..100){
        if (cancelCounter) {
            cancelCounter = false
            break
        }
        bc.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG, i.toString())
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        d("number", i.toString())
        sendBroadcast(bc)
    }
}
```

You may not have direct access to the object from main - if not then you should create this class with a singleton pattern ;)

I don't code in kotlin enough to now the "right way" to do it, but some links to the right way:
https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-create-a-singleton-class-in-kotlin
https://medium.com/swlh/singleton-class-in-kotlin-c3398e7fd76b

Both of these links have some information about why they make the decisions they make in the structure pattern, and some of how the code behind for the implementations works too ;)

Comment: wow, that use of singleton classes made my day, many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

For someone who also learn Kotlin I will post my solution as well. It looks pretty simple, however, there probably could be more solutions.

I created a simple Kotlin object like:

```
object Trigger {
    var triggerStop = 0
    fun getTrigger(): Int{
        return triggerStop
    }
}
```

As you can see variable `triggerStop` can be changed and called with function `getTrigger()`

So I added this object into MainActivity to buttons' setOnClickListeners:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var i:Intent
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        i = Intent(this, IntentServiceExample::class.java)

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener{
            Trigger.triggerStop = 0 // this variable will be checked in IntentService
            startService(i)
        }
        buttonEnd.setOnClickListener{
            Trigger.triggerStop = 1 // this variable will be checked in IntentService
            stopService(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I put this object into my IntentService. In a loop that I want to be stopped by user interaction I put a check like in @Watachiaieto's answer.

```
fun counter(bc: Intent){
    for (i in 1..100){
        val stopIt = Trigger.getTrigger() // get trigger value
        if (stopIt == 1) {
            break
        }
        bc.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG, i.toString())
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        sendBroadcast(bc)
    }
}
```